# Program won't run (.exe can not be found)

Tags: c++

I never had this problem before, first time doing a graphic QT program. This is pretty much a copy/paste of my teachers example, I imported a turtlelib.lib.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLfz3.png

Answer (score 0):

First, after compilation, can you find the `exe` at the indicated location?
If no, i suggest to check the `Configuration Properties > Build Events > Post Build Event`: your project might be moving the executable somewhere else.

Comment: I can't find the exe at the indicated location. Sorry but where do I to find common properties?

Comment: on the left, you have your solution explorer. Right click on it > `Properties` (i corrected a typo, `Configuration`, not `common`)

Comment: i have the config properties up but don't see build events
http://i.imgur.com/HaUAnyg.png

Comment: does your solution recompile properly? testertester > `Rebuild`?

Comment: Seems it cannon open the file 'turtlelib.lib', i added to to the "additional directory" and the linker. Maybe I should move it to the same folder as testertester

Comment: ok, or you can drag and drop the `turtlelib.lib` in the project